# Delete element on first level of a list

Tags: scheme

Define recursive function DELETE with two arguments : an atom A and a list L that returns a new list in which all occurrences of the atom A on the first level of the list L have been removed.

Example: `(Delete ‘a ‘(m a (m a)))` return `(m (m a))`.

Comment: This sounds more like a homework exercise than a question. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your description. And you should try for yourself and report back with your code if you have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the question stated in the body, which is slightly more difficult and different from what you wrote in the title. The easiest solution would be to use one of the built-in procedures - for instance, if your interpreter provides [`remove*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._remove%2A%29%29) it'll do the trick. This is the recommended way, avoid reinventing the wheel:

```
(remove* '(a) '(m a (m a) a))
=> '(m (m a))
```

But I guess you want to implement this from scratch. The solution follows closely the standard template for traversing an input list and returning an output list. I'll give you some hints, but I won't spoil the fun of finding your own answer. Fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (delete ele lst)
  (cond (<???>                        ; if the list is empty
         <???>)                       ; then return the empty list
        (<???>                        ; is current element equal to `ele`?
         (delete ele <???>))          ; then skip it and advance recursion
        (else                         ; otherwise
         (cons <???>                  ; `cons` current element
               (delete ele <???>))))) ; and also advance recursion
```

It works as expected:

```
(delete 'a '(m a (m a) a))
=> '(m (m a))
```

As a side note, adapting the code to answer the question in the title should be easy: as soon as the *first* element is found, skip it and return the rest of the list, it won't be necessary to advance the recursion any further. Left as an exercise for the reader.